# Serialize user defined CLR object to Azure Storage Table

Tags: c#, serialization, azure, azure-storage, protobuf-net

If i have a user defined CLR objects that all inherit from TableEntity, for example these CLR's:

```
public class Person : TableEntity
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string Prefix { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
   public List<string> AList { get; set; }
   public List<Urls> ListUrls { get; set; }
}

public class Address : TableEntity
{
   public string Street { get; set; }
   public string Zipcode { get; set; }
   public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
}

public class Urls : TableEntity
{
   public Uri Real { get; set; }
   public Uri Fake { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: I know that the properties and the classes have to be decorated with attributes for `Protobuf-net`. But to keep it simple I left those out for now.*

And I want to convert this to `byte[]` using `Protobuf-net` and serialize that to the Windows Azure Storage and deserialize it back to these CLR objects. How can I accomplish this?

I followed [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#create-table) tutorial, but I got stuck with the `byte[]`. I don't know how to just write a `byte[]` to the table.

If the question isn't clear, let me know i'll try to clearify more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating an exact copy of the CLR objects and made them inherit from TableEntity for serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Azure storage with TableEntity is a full framework. I would suggest that trying to do both at the same time is problematic. Perhaps separate the two things. For example:

```
public class Person { // note no base class
    //...
}
```

Now serialize that via MemoryStream to get your byte[] (maojg sure to use ToArray(), not GetBuffer()).

Then separately:

```
public class PersonBlob : TableEntity {
    public byte[] Data {get;set;}
}
```

(You might even be able to use generics here to support all types at once, but I don't know for sure).

You could also add, say, ToPerson / FromPerson utility methods to get between the two.

Any use?

Comment: Looks great! You said that I might even be able to use generics. What did you mean by that? Isn't `public List<string> AList { get; set; }` supported for serialization?

Comment: @Quoter I mean: public class EntityBlob-of-T : TableEntity { public byte[] Data {get;set;} }

Comment: I was trying out your solution and the To.Array() method always returns 0 bytes. WHen i look into the Azure table, the whole object got saved, in stead of just the Data byte[]. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: @Quoter a: 0 bytes means no data - did you mark any members as ProtoMember etc?

Comment: Well there was data in the CLR object. Everything was filled. Yes i marked all as protomember. I think I know what is going wrong. There are too many derrives and interfaces i have to include. But can't add references of those class lib project because it causes a 'circular reference' message from VS2013 or something like that.